# How do I filter api geocode google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, geocode

How can I filter the result of geocode API with region or bounds parameters ?

Example with filter region:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=tokyo&region=it

Why return "Tokyo Japan" if I have filtered with parameter "region=it" (Italy) ?

Example with filter bounds with the coordinates of Italy (I think):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=tokyo&bounds=47.092,18.7975999%7C35.4897,6.6267201

Why return "Tokyo Japan"??

Please Help me!

Thanks

Chiara

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `region` parameter and `bounds` parameter is only a bias, not a restriction. Please check the Geocoding API documentation:

- Region Biasing: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#RegionCodes
- Viewport Biasing: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#Viewports